# What is your prefered toolkit / program for 3D visualisations of data?

Tags: data, visualization

If you recorded data which represents some physical value in space (e.g. electron density) and you need to explore this dynamically in 3d (say you have a isosurface and you change the value it represents) what toolkit/program would you use?

Personally I used MayaVi and it has all the all the features I could need. Unfortunately it is sometimes unstable and often slow. So in principle I am looking for equally powerfull alternatives.

Edit: I know this should probably not be in the physics SE but I think the answer to my question could be relevant for many physicists.

Comment: Make-a-list questions are generally discouraged, and this topic has little relevance to *physics* as such. You might search on Stack Overflow and have a look at [the Scientific Computation beta](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) site. Indeed, I will ask the SciComp mods if they would like me to migrate it.

Comment: I think this may fall under "not constructive" (meaning it's not the kind of question that fits on any SE site), perhaps in addition to "off topic."

Comment: The SciComp mods don't seem to want it in the present form.

Comment: Not constructive/off topic? How can analysing ones data efficiently not be constructive? I guess I'm not thinking like a theorist here, lacking imagination. Oddly enought all the journals I read seem to show what I'm talking about. Guess people don't read Science, Nature, PRL, etc. any more.

Comment: Btw: How is this not off-topic: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11451/what-does-the-raw-data-from-a-particle-collision-look-like?rq=1 ??  Oh wait, it relates to HEP. Must be valid I guess.