# How do they draw collision pictures in Atlas?

Tags: large-hadron-collider, image-processing

Is the picture below a simulation? How to they draw these pictures? The picture is from [here](http://arstechnica.com/science/2013/11/elusive-higgs-decay-channel-spotted-particle-looks-ever-more-standard/).

[image]

Comment: This looks like a combination of known sensor positions (yellow and green), with the orange lines the assumed paths of particles based on sensor readings... I think this is what you are looking for http://atlas.ch/news/2013/higgs-into-fermions.html

Comment: This kind of image is called an "event display", and as @Luke says it is a visualization of the parts of the detector that were triggered during the event and the reconstructed trajectories (i.e. the output of a significant step in the analysis).

Comment: Related question on the site which might (partially) answer your question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11451/what-does-the-data-in-various-stages-of-analysis-from-a-particle-collision-look and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4063/a-reference-request-for-real-world-experimental-data. I won't have time to write a proper answer any time soon as I have in-laws in town.

Answer (score 3):

This picture is not a simulation, it is an actual collision event. *But* it could have been either: both real and simulated events can be visualized in this way. Everything is done mainly by using the GEANT4 software package.

(As partially mentioned in the comments, the small boxes are deposits of energy in detectors; different colour for each detector. The lines, both straight and curved, are the reconstructed tracks of particles. And the blue cones are hadronic jets, which are actually spread out.)